# LED HD TV as a monitor for post processing purpose

Tags: post-processing, resolution, monitors

Can I use a 47" 3d led hd tv with my pc to post process my photos? I am not sure how the quality will be on such a big screen photo being of some 4900x3600 approx.

Comment: Can you use it? Probably. Will it be optimal? Not at all. HD TVs are low resolution for their dimensions, and you might struggle to get them color calibrated.

Comment: Is your tv resolution the usual 1920x1080? Resolution is what counts, not the inches. Besides, even with the 16:9 resolution the physical screen is sometimes not truly 16:9 in dimensions.

Comment: @Esa: Yes the TV resolution is 1920x1080.

Comment: Remember than the term "LED TV" is a marketing term that has the potential to be misleading.  LED Televisions are in fact LCD televisions; the LED part refers to the technology used for the backlight.  It's becoming a meaningless term, as it's now becoming the norm for LCD televisions to have an LED-based backlight.  Advantage of LED backlight is the ability to make the display thinner.  It doesn't necessarily lead to better backlight uniformity as it's usually side-illuminated using strips of LEDs. It also has virtually no effect on "image quality".